# How to discard records in SPSS Modeler by row/field numbers?

Tags: spss-modeler

I have a number of records with no meaning. Would like to discard from row 1 to 20 for example.
What is the expression to input in the Select-->Discard Node? Or any other node to suggest?

Thank you in advance!!
[image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fyd0.png)

Answer (score 1):

The `Select` node is the correct node to use for this.

IBM SPSS Modeler has a built-in function that returns the row number - `@INDEX` - and you can, therefore, use the `Select` node in the "Include" mode along with the condition:

```
@INDEX > 20
```

This will discard the first 20 rows of data from your data set.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the last 5 rows from a dataset?