# How to discard last 'N' records using Select node in SPSS modeler?

Tags: spss-modeler

The title says it all. Working on a use case where I need to trim both the top and bottom of a dataset at every new run. It is not fixed how much will be removed every run, just 'N' amount of records.

I was able to discard the first N records using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58222516/how-to-discard-records-in-spss-modeler-by-row-field-numbers) post. However, I am not sure how the last few can be removed. I looked up the documentation and the negative sign does not work (atleast the way I need it to). This is my first time using SPSS, so any help is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would probably be to sort your data so that the last 5 records become the first 5 records and then follow the instructions from the referenced post.

Alternatively, you can use the `Aggregate` node to get the total number of records in the dataset and then merge that number back into your primary dataset. You can use the `Select` node with the condition `(count - @INDEX - 1) <= N` where 'count' is the field with the total number of records in the dataset and `N` is the number of records that you are looking to discard.